# Tab replaced to space automatically in Delphi11

Tags: delphi, ide, editor, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using delphi 11.0(28.0.42600.6491).
Typing some tabs in code editor, and after a short pause, typing any character.
Then, I found tabs are replaced to space automatically.

And it seems to be happened when input character after already exists line.
My problem is like GIF image(animated).

I don't want that. tabs must be tabs strictly.
Is there any setting or way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE Settings "Use tab character" and "Keep trailing blanks". Note you would also need to uncheck "Cursor through tabs" to see the cursor jump otherwise it will go space by space through tabs.

The "Keep trailing blanks" setting is really "Keep trailing whitespace" and deletes any tabs and spaces at the end of lines after a short delay.  The cursor stays past the end of the line so if you type something it then puts in spaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I additionaly updated my report.
I tried doing that option, but the problem isn't solved.

Wondering it's based on Version(Delphi11) or my computer's environment.

Comment: @P.Miz I see that as well. Tab + quickly pressing something else means the tab stays. Pause and it replaces it with spaces. With the _Use tab character_ setting off only spaces appear in the editor. Seems like duplicated functionality with one version having no apparent way to turn it off.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly correct. If input tab and quickly any other character, the problem is never happend. I searched for useful content on help document, but nothing I could find. Maybe no way to solve that like you said, I thought. I try to wait for other comment for while, and close this report, thanks.

Comment: You also need to enable `Keep trailing blanks` or Delphi automatically removes blank characters on the end of the line. In Delphi 10.3 this only happens when going to new line. But in Delphi 11 it might be linked to some predefined interval.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks for your reply. I began to think give up, but checking "trailing blanks turn" option lead me resolving this problem clearly. Thanks for all!

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks. Guess it is really "Keep trailing whitespace" as it also deletes tabs after a short delay and not just spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (in my opinion) that started in 10.4.  I have reported it as RSP-36776:  https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36776

Comment: Thanks for your useful information. If that's a bug, possible to be fixed in the future, isn't it. I'll remember that, thanks.